# Is there an arXiv for Beamer presentations of scientific work?

Tags: journals, arxiv

When I give a "Beamer talk" I put in a lot of effort making the slides, and trying to give an efficient presentation of my work. The end product is often around 20 pages of figures, definitions, theorems, ideas, all color coded, and thoughtfully placed in the frame.

After the talk I frequently am asked if my slides will be available, and I might be handed a thumb drive so that I will do the transfer right then. Because of this, I usually post my slides on my personal website.

So, given all the extra work that goes into making this document that will accompany my public presentation of my work, I wonder two things.

1. Does there exist a Beamer arXiv? Is there a place to add the Beamer file to the arXiv?
2. Is there a journal that publishes slide presentations? If not, why not?
   Doesn't it seem like we should create a journal-like entity to publish and promote the work we are already doing? It could be something of a "Scientific American" for Mathematics.

Comment: Good question, but perhaps not for this site.  There's nothing particularly mathematical about it.  This may explain the close votes.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but I have to wonder why your question is restricted to beamer presentations? Just like the arXiv is not restricted to LaTeX papers, why should a site like the one you mention not accept keynotes and power points? That said, I also post my slides on my website, with source code. One of the great things about arXiv is that whenever a paper is written in LaTeX, it is always provided with the source code. I saw you do not post your beamer source code, and I was hoping you would consider changing that.

Comment: Perhaps there's a more appropriate place to ask the question?

Comment: I have no particular affinity to beamer for such a publication, so in principal keynote / power point, etc would also be fine.

Comment: Perhaps http://academia.stackexchange.com/ ??

Comment: About posting the .tex source, I guess I like to keep just one more layer between my work and would-be copy-and-pasters. Maybe my concern is unrealistic?

Comment: The reason I posted it here versus at academia.stackexchange.com is that I am trying to think of ways that mathematicians in particular can do a better job at advertising our work, it's beauty, etc.

Comment: Regarding concerns about posting tex sources:  http://arxiv.org/help/faq/whytex. The discussion there applies to this case, except that when you post to your own homepage, it doesn't help much as a timestamped archive for priority claims. A website of the type you seek would help in that regard.

Comment: A related question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135550/collective-slide-hosting-for-mathematics

Comment: PS, when you put "one more layer between my work and would-be copy-and-pasters", this is what happens: https://twitter.com/KyleCranmer/status/465935221796634624/photo/1

Comment: figshare comes to mind. they host any types of files, are timestamped and versioned, and will survive longer than a personal webpage.

Answer (score 5):

Slideshare.net is your friend.

Comment: They do not seem to support Beamer, do they?